# oracle , sql , trigger

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER "CPI"."TRGPRODOFFRPRICE" 
AFTER UPDATE or INSERT ON CPI_LOADER_EXEMPTIONS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
table_name varchar(32);
BEGIN
 if substr(:new.SID_ID,1,3) = 'POP' then
  table_name := 'PROD_OFFR_PRICE_CHARGE';
 else 
  table_name := 'PROD_OFFR_PRICE_ALTERATION';
 end if;
 execute immediate 'UPDATE  :1 set CPI_EXEMPTION=:2 WHERE SID_ID=:3'   using table_name, :new.FLAG, :new.SID_ID;
END;
```

Based on comments i edited into this form, which looks better, but when trying to insert value into table which launches trigger i am getting error 'invalid table name', any idea what is causing this ? wrong tab var declaration possibly?

Comment: As always start simple ... get a simple trigger working OK then progress in small steps to your complex goal outlined above ... benefit is any error you get is easily identified as the last change ... errors in attempting above definition could point to too many causes

Comment: this looks "ok" but you want to go full dynamic sql -- just having the table as a variable won't work

Comment: [Should I use tags in titles?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): "Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for". I'd struggle to edit your question title (your real chance to "sell" your question to potential answerers) since it's *entirely* tags. Please edit your title to something a little more *descriptive*.

Comment: You can't pass identifiers (table or column names) as a parameter to `execute immediate`. You can only pass real values

Answer (score 0):

Try this (real PL/SQL):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgSample
AFTER UPDATE or INSERT ON EXEMPTIONS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   sid varchar(10);
   sidVal varchar(100);
   table_name varchar(32);
   flag int;
BEGIN
  sid   := substr(:new.SID_ID,1,3);
  flag  := :new.FLAG;
  sidVal := :new.SID_ID;
  if sid = 'POP' then
    table_name := 'PROD_VAL';
  else 
    table_name := 'PROD_VAL2';
  end if;
  execute immediate 'UPDATE ' || table_name 
                    || ' set EXEMPTION=sidVal WHERE SID_ID=:x' using sidVal;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

AFter all only these changes were neccessary: 
        'change var to varchar2 for table_name:'
only slight update on execute statement:
      'execute immediate 'UPDATE  :1 set CPI_EXEMPTION=:2 WHERE SID_ID=:3'    using table_name, :new.FLAG, :new.SID_ID;'

thanks for all comments, they ´ve helped me a lot. And need to say a i learn a lot.